# Solving matrix using Gaussian elimination and a parameter

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, parametric, gaussian-elimination

$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}   & 2x_{2}  &    &     & ax_{5}                       & x_{6}  & = & -2 \\
-x_{1}  & -2x_{2} &    &     & (-1-a)x_{5}                  & -x_{6} & = & 3  \\
-2x_{1} & -4x_{2} & -x_{3} & 2x_{4}  & a^{2}x_{5} &    & = & 7  \\
x_{1}   & 2x_{2}  & x_{3}  & -2x_{4} & (a+2)x_{5}                   & -x_{6} & = & -6
\end{bmatrix} $

Solve the set of equations using parameter 'a'.

Comment: Yes, it's straight from an university exam, I doubled checked it (twice). I am stumped about it.

Comment: The problem I had was that in the end some my variables were depending on each other like x1=a^2-2a-1-x2. I don't know if it's and acceptable answer or I have made a mistake. Or maybe there is a problem with my basic understanding of Gaussian elimination (I haven't solved such wide matrices yet). I could deduce all that from a correct answer.

Comment: I tried some 'a' and they all seem to work well so I assume that I reduced it correctly. Just for confirmation: is it fine in a task like this that some of my final values of x's will be depending on each other?

Comment: That sounds right, I just wanted to be sure having solved so many tasks which wouldn't give you free variables. Huge thanks!

Comment: Why did you put brackets around the system?

Comment: Why shouldn't I? It's an exact reproduction from a book of mine.

Comment: What function does it perform? It's a system of equations, not a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a lot shorter to write as an augmented matrix if you can get used to the style:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
-1 & -2 &  0  &  0  & -1-a  & -1  & 3  \\
-2 & -4 & -1 & 2  & a^{2} &   0  & 7  \\
1  & 2  & 1  & -2 & a+2    & -1  & -6
\end{array}\right]$

Row 2 $\leftarrow$ Row 2 + Row 1;
Row 3 $\leftarrow$ Row 3 + 2(Row 1);
Row 4 $\leftarrow$ Row 4 - Row 1

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & -1  & 0  & 1  \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2  & a^{2}+2a &   2  & 3  \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4
\end{array}\right]$

Row 2 $\leftrightarrow$ Row 4

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2  & a^{2}+2a &   2  & 3  \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & -1  & 0  & 1  \\
\end{array}\right]$

Row 3 $\leftarrow$ Row 3 + Row 2; Row 4 = Row 4 $\times (-1)$

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & a^{2}+2a+2 &   0  & -1  \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & 1  & 0  & -1  \\
\end{array}\right]$

Row 3 $\leftrightarrow$ Row 4

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4 \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & 1  & 0  & -1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & a^{2}+2a+2 &   0  & -1  \\
\end{array}\right]$

What happens next depends on whether $a^2+2a+2=0$. If so, the last line of the matrix tells us the system is inconsistent and we **stop**. Assuming $a\in\mathbb{R}$ there are no solutions to $a^2+2a+2=0$ and we continue:

Row 4 $\leftarrow$ Row 4 / $(a^{2}+2a+2)$

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4 \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & 1  & 0  & -1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 1 &   0  & -1 / (a^{2}+2a+2) \\
\end{array}\right]$

Row 4 $\leftarrow$ Row 4 - Row 3

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & a     & 1   & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4 \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & 1  & 0  & -1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 &   0  & (a^2+2a+1) / (a^{2}+2a+2) \\
\end{array}\right]$

Now consistency requires $a^2+2a+1=0$, which has only 1 solution: $a=-1$.

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  &  0  &  0  & -1     & 1   & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 1  & -2 & 2    & -2  & -4 \\
0 & 0 &  0  &  0  & 1  & 0  & -1  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 &   0  & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]$

You can start back-substituting now, but let's continue to reduced row-echelon form:

Row 1 $\leftarrow$ Row 1 + Row 3; Row 2 $\leftarrow$ Row 2 - 2(Row 3)

$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
1  & 2  & 0 &  0  &  0 &  1  & -3 \\
0  & 0  & 1 & -2  &  0 & -2  & -2 \\
0  & 0  & 0 &  0  &  1 &  0  & -1 \\
0  & 0  & 0 &  0  &  0 &  0  &  0 \\
\end{array}\right]$  which we can read as:
$\begin{array}{l}
x_1+2x_2+x_6=-3\\
x_3  -2x_4   -2x_6  = -2 \\
x_5  = -1 \\
{}
\end{array}$

Columns 2,4,6 have no leading 1s, so $x_2,x_4,x_6$ become free parameters and we express the other variables in terms of those. We can write the equations as:

$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\\x_6\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2x_2&&-x_6&-3\\x_2&&\\&2x_4&+2x_6&-2\\&x_4&&\\&&&-1\\&&x_6\end{bmatrix}=x_2
\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+x_4\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+x_6\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\2\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\-2\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Any arithmetic errors are not mine but are the fault of [Satan's affine transformations](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=affine+translations+for+satan+himself).